# Is it possible to delete the "userX added a commit to repoY that referenced this issue Z hours ago" message on an issue's discussion?

Tags: git, github

My company uses the Issues functionality of Github heavily, and they have discussions about specific open issues on the page of the issues themselves. For the issue I've been assigned to, I've been having to rewrite the commit message over and over again (because I've been having to commit over and over again while I try and figure out how to squash merge).

As a result, the message  "userX added a commit to repoY that referenced this issue Z hours ago" is polluting the discussion thread and makes it difficult to read. Is there any way to get rid of these messages?

I'm not asking how to remove a commit (in general I think the only way to do that is to squash/rebase), I'm just asking how to delete these messages in an issue's discussion page.